# Photo Tagging in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What I want to know is how can I make a drag selection box using JavaScript.

What I mean, is when you click the left mouse button and drag, a "wire" (I don't know the term for it) should appear , like on your desktop.

Clicking and dragging on an image and when released a search box should appear below the dragged area.

I'm sure this is possible, but I didn't find any example.So , can you help me ?

Comment: Crosshair is the word you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for the word crosshair

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done like this

```
function getCursorPosition(e)
{
e = e || window.event;
if (e)
    {
    if (e.pageX || e.pageX == 0) return [e.pageX,e.pageY];
    var dE = document.documentElement || {};
    var dB = document.body || {};
    if ((e.clientX || e.clientX == 0) && ((dB.scrollLeft || dB.scrollLeft == 0) || (dE.clientLeft || dE.clientLeft == 0))) return [e.clientX + (dE.scrollLeft || dB.scrollLeft || 0) - (dE.clientLeft || 0),e.clientY + (dE.scrollTop || dB.scrollTop || 0) - (dE.clientTop || 0)];
    }
return null;
}

function mousedown(e)
{
var mxy = getCursorPosition(e);
var box = document.getElementById("sel_box");
box.orig_x = mxy[0];
box.orig_y = mxy[1];
box.style.left = mxy[0]+"px";
box.style.top = mxy[1]+"px";
box.style.display = "block";
document.onmousemove = mousemove;
document.onmouseup = mouseup;
}

function mousemove(e)
{
var mxy = getCursorPosition(e);
var box = document.getElementById("sel_box");
box.style.width = (mxy[0]-box.orig_x)+"px";
box.style.height = (mxy[1]-box.orig_y)+"px";
}

function mouseup(e)
{
var box = document.getElementById("sel_box");
box.style.display = "none";
box.style.width = "0";
box.style.height = "0";
document.onmousemove = function(){};
document.onmouseup = function(){};
}
```

document.onmousedown = mousedown;

@Praveen Kumar

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that can do this. You can try using [jQuery Resize Plugin](https://github.com/adeelejaz/jquery-image-resize) to achieve what you want.

> **aeImageResize** is a jQuery plugin to dynamically resize the images without distorting the proportions.

**Example**

```
$(function() {
  $( ".resizeme" ).aeImageResize({ height: 250, width: 250 });
});
```

Extending this plugin and in the `complete` function, you can make it as a textarea.

Comment: i dont want to resize the image. what i want to achieve is like this demo http://codecanyon.net/item/fototag/full_screen_preview/123037

Comment: only using pure javascript

Comment: Comparison: **Pure JavaScript** - 1000 lines of code, unmaintainable, doesn't work under all browsers. **jQuery** - Less than 100 lines of code, maintainable, works under most of the browsers. @KishoreKumar Think about this and let me know. :)

Comment: Ok i will use jQuery how can i get the result like in the demo just click and drag and when released i want a search box to be appeared below the dragged area for tagging friends. i will do the php part.

Comment: Ha ha... In the `complete` function, give something like `$(this).append('<input type="search" />')` or something like that. :)

Comment: i saw in a website that facebook uses only pure JS for their site and they have photo tagging

Comment: i saw this in another website. the question was same like mine and the asker said it worked for him

Answer (score 0):

URL Link :-
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

using jQuery ui api.

This is the best drag selection technique..

Comment: I dont want drag and drop like this. In your computer screen you can click and hold the left mouse button and drag. I need that kind of drag and when released the selected area on the image should be there till i tag friends.